# SQL Pivot Error and Compatibility Level

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50be3/5) that works.  However when I run this in MS SQL Server 2008 I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'pivot'. You may need to set the compatibility
>   level of the current database to a higher value to enable this
>   feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER
>   DATABASE.

I am basically using what I found from another question, I don't know exactly what is going on but it is giving me good data with my test sample set.

I did try the commented out `ALTER DATABASE COMPATIBILITY` which did not work.

I am ultimately going to be putting this into a C# application where the users won't have more access to the database other than being able to query and update tables.

Comment: Did you change out the #TempTable in the ALTER DATABASE statement to your actual database name?

Comment: Nope, that might have been the problem.  Just set it to the database name and it looks like the query ran!